# How to forward a 'line break' in a url using markdown without breaking link?

Tags: url, markdown, telegram-bot, line-breaks

I'm using 'markdown' to send information via a url to a telegram bot that parses the information.

I would like to make the information I'm sending more presentable and easy to read, and so I would like to insert line breaks.

The issue I'm running across is that entering literal "line breaks" in a link, breaks the link.

Is there a character like `\n` or `</br>` that when entered in markdown syntax produces a line break? If not is there another way to send a line break to telegram bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `%0A` in your URL for telegram to begin a new line.

This URL encoded line feed character works regardless of used parse mode (Markdown, MarkdownV2 or HTML).